# OpenMP - Counting comparisons in pattern matching

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, pattern-matching, openmp

I have the following algorithm, which I created by trying to make a sequential pattern finding algorithm parallel.

As I was getting a race condition when trying to count the comparisons made, I created a temp variable and attempted to perform a reduction, however I am still not getting the same amount of comparisons as the sequential algorithm.

```
int hostMatch(long *comparisons)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, lastI = textLength-patternLength;
    long comparisons_tmp = 0;
    int found = textLength + 1;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:comparisons_tmp) \
                         schedule(static)                  \
                         num_threads(4)                     \
                         default(none)                       \
                         shared(found, comparisons)           \
                         private(j, k)                         \
                         firstprivate(lastI, textData, patternData, patternLength)
    for(i = 0; i<= lastI; i++)
    {
         if(i < found)
         {
            k=i; j=0;
            while(textData[k] == patternData[j] && j < patternLength)
            {
                k++; j++; comparisons_tmp++;
            }
            if(j == patternLength)
            {
                #pragma omp critical(check)
                {
                    if(found > i)
                       found = i;
                }
            }
         }
    }
    *comparisons = comparisons_tmp;
 // return (found < textLength + 1) ? found : -1;
    if(found < textLength + 1)
         return found;
    else
         return -1;
}
```

This code returns the amount of comparisons
`3994004000` for test0, whereas
`3996002000` for the sequential algorithm comparisons.

The original sequential code was as follows:

```
int hostMatch(long *comparisons)
{
int i,j,k, lastI;

i=0;
j=0;
k=0;
lastI = textLength-patternLength;
    *comparisons=0;

while (i<=lastI && j<patternLength)
{
            (*comparisons)++;
    if (textData[k] == patternData[j])
    {
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        k=i;
        j=0;
    }
}
if (j == patternLength)
    return i;
else
    return -1;
}
```

I am unsure whether I am incrementing the comparisons_tmp variable in the wrong place, any help would be grateful. Test0 contains a pattern file of 1999 A's followed by a B, with a text file of 199999 A's followed by a B.

Comment: What is `test0`? What is the sequential algorithm? Why do you expect the comparisons to be equal in both serial and parallel? Please provide a full [mcve] of both.

Comment: I apologize for the layout and formatting of this question, this is my first time using stack overflow, thanks for any help available.

Answer (score 1):

The `comparisons_tmp` should be incremented outside of the `while`-loop. You are missing now the first comparison, e.g., if the first character of patter does not match the comparisons is not incremented at all.

However, note that by fixing the counter position, parallel algorithm will most likely have much more comparisons, because OpenMP does *not* guarantee the order which the loop is executed. This means that most likely some threads will do comparisons with `i` larger than the final value of `found`.